# Leek ashes - why?

Tags: leeks

I have seen restaurants with dishes containing "Leek ashes".
What do the ashes add to the dish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen [references](http://forums.egullet.org/index.php?/topic/87032-leek-ashes/) to leek ashes providing a smoky note to sauces and that this is a Spanish origin technique. Using it as a coating for steak also appears to be trendy, so I'd guess it's again for a subtle smoky flavour.

I'm most familiar with ashes being part of cheese.  For example, Morbier has a layer of vegetable ash in the middle, and some goat cheeses are rolled in ash.  I assume that originally this would have been for a preservative effect, but is now part of the character of the cheeses.

Comment: In your reference someone gives instructions to make it. It sounds like it would be interesting to try.